# jquery - hide/show state of the page not been saved to localStorage

Tags: jquery, eclipse, html, jsp, local-storage

In my table I have a "Hide" button infront of each row. when you wanna hide a row from the table you click on the button on the row which you need to hide. When it's clicked the row is hidden and the button turns to a "Show" button so if you want you can get that data back again in your table.

HTML code snippet for the button

```
<button class="hide" id="hiding" type="button" value="Hide">Hide</button>
                        <button class="show" id="showing" type="button" value="Show" style="display:none;">Show</button>
```

jquery code snippet for this function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function(){
    $(".hide").on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var tr = $this.closest('tr');
            $this.hide();
            $this.next().show();
            $(tr).find(".duecolour, .i, .delival, .binval").hide();
});
$(".show").on('click', function(){
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).prev().show();
            $(tr).find(".duecolour, .i, .delival, .binval").show();
            });
});
```

How do I keep my page status (either with hidden rows or vice versa) saved even after page is refreshed using localStorage?

I tried following inside "hide" function to test but didn't work.

```
localStorage.setItem('d', $("#data_display").html());
var newData = localStorage.getItem('d');
return $("#data_display").html(newData);
```

EDIT - Adding the JSP code here

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="com.chcec.humanResources.HeldPosition"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Set"%>
<%@page import="com.chcec.humanResources.Person"%>
<%@page import="com.chcec.humanResources.Position"%>
<%@page import="com.chcec.humanResources.StaffMember"%>
<%@page import="com.chcec.materials.criticalparts.FreightForwarder"%>
<%@page import="com.chcec.materials.criticalparts.RequiredDelivery"%>
<%@page import="com.chcec.materials.criticalparts.Vendor"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.criterion.Order"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@taglib uri="/chcec/spannernet" prefix="chcec"%>
<chcec:nocache />
<chcec:hibernate>

    <%
        Session sess = (Session) pageContext.getAttribute("hibernatesession");

            StaffMember user = StaffMember.getAuthenticatedUser(request.getRemoteUser(), sess);
            pageContext.setAttribute("user", user);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<RequiredDelivery> requiredParts = sess.createCriteria(RequiredDelivery.class).list();
            Collections.sort(requiredParts);
            pageContext.setAttribute("requiredParts", requiredParts);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<FreightForwarder> freightForwarders = sess.createCriteria(FreightForwarder.class)
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("name")).list();
            pageContext.setAttribute("freightForwarders", freightForwarders);

            //TODO: Use POS_POS_RESPONSIBILITY for this
            Position pos = (Position) sess.get(Position.class, 62L);
            List<Person> mcs = new ArrayList<Person>();
            Set<HeldPosition> hps = pos.getAppointees();
            for (HeldPosition hp : hps) {
                if (hp.getHolder().isStaff()) {
                    mcs.add(hp.getHolder());
                }
            }
            //List<StaffMember> mles = sess.createCriteria(StaffMember.class).addOrder(Order.asc("name")).list();
            pageContext.setAttribute("mcs", mcs);

            boolean canOrder = true;
            boolean canFulfill = true;

            pageContext.setAttribute("canFulfill", canFulfill);
            pageContext.setAttribute("canOrder", canOrder);
    %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Critical Parts</title>
<jsp:include page="/include/htmlhead.inc" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/matStyle.css">

<script src="scripts/matScript.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <jsp:include page="/include/header.inc" />
    <jsp:include page="/include/layout24_a.inc" />
    <jsp:include page="/include/layout24_b.inc" />

    <h1>Critical Parts</h1>

    <table class="key">
        <col style='width: 20px;' />
        <col />
        <tr>
            <th colspan='2' style='text-align: left;'>Key:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='today'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Due today</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='tomorrow'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Due tomorrow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='inTransit'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Received but not binned</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='gr'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Received</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="required" id="data_display">
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 100px;' />
        <col style='width: 160px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 100px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 120px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 120px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 140px;' />
        <col />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 150px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 80px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 80px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 30px;' />
        <col style='text-align: center; width: 30px;' />
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="due_header">Due</th>
                <th>Vendor</th>
                <th>Freight</th>
                <th>AWB</th>
                <th>PO</th>
                <th>PN</th>
                <th>Part Description</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>MLE</th>
                <th>Engine</th>
                <th>Pegged</th>
                <th>Delivered</th>
                <th>GR</th>
                <th>Binned</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${requiredParts}" var="part">
                <tr id="order${part.id}" class="parts">
                    <td class="duecolour" id="sort"><fmt:formatDate value="${part.due}"
                            pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" /></td>
                    <td class="i">${part.vendor}</td>
                    <td class="i"><c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${not empty part.freight.iconFile}">
                                <img alt="${part.freight.name}"
                                    src="images/${part.freight.iconFile}" class="freight_logo" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>${part.freight.name}</c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose></td>
                    <td class="i">
                    <a href="${part.trackingLink}" target="_blank">${part.awb}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="i">${part.purchaseOrder}</td>
                    <td class="i">${part.partNumber}</td>
                    <td class="i">${part.partDescription}</td>
                    <td class="i">${part.comments}</td>
                    <td class="i"><a href='javascript:view("${part.mle.usercode}");void 0'>${part.mle.name}</a></td>
                    <td class="i">${part.engine}</td>
                     <td class="i" align="center">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${part.pegged == true}"><img src="images/tick.gif" name="peg" alt="${part.pegged == true}" class="pegval"/></c:when>
                            <c:otherwise></c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </td> 
                    <td class="delival"><c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${not empty part.delivery}">
                                <fmt:formatDate value="${part.delivery.date}"
                                    pattern="MMM/dd HH:mm" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise></c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose></td>
                    <td class="i"><c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${canFulfill}">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="gr"/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                              <input type="checkbox" />
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose></td>
                    <td  align="center" class="binval">
                        <c:choose >
                            <c:when test="${canFulfill}">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="bin" value="${part.id}"/>
                            </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="bin"/> 
                        </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="hide" id="hiding" type="button" value="Hide">Hide</button>
                        <button class="show" id="showing" type="button" value="Show" style="display:none;">Show</button>
                    </td>
                </tr> 

            </c:forEach>
</tbody>
    </table>


    <jsp:include page="/include/layout234_d.inc" />
    <jsp:include page="/include/footer.jsp"><jsp:param
            name="owner" value="fcec398" /></jsp:include>
</body>
    </html>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">${error}</c:if>
</chcec:hibernate>
```

Comment: When you click on hide button is there any class assigned to your tr?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or show your jsp code?

Comment: @Meghashah when you click on hide button it hides the "hide" button, display the "show" button and hide the <td>s with the classes "duecolour, I, delival, binval" so only the <td> with the "show" button remains.

Comment: @VPK Just edited the question with the JSP code

Comment: Does the `show` and `hide` button's current state remains after the page reload? If that so, you can use its display property to know whether to hide or display the corresponding row..

Comment: @VPK unfortunately no, the hide/show button statuses don't get recorded on page reload